# how to get website root path in c#?

Tags: c#

In c# code, I need to write src for an image. Does anyone know how to get website root path in c#? My folder structure is UI/Image
I found that when I use

```
string rootpath=Page.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

If run the application in debug model, it works. But if run it by typing url directly, it won't show image. The property of the image is http://image/turnon.bmp which should be http://localhost/image/turnon.bmp

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An easy way is use `MapPath` with the `~` wildcard:

```
string imagePath = MapPath("~/image/turnon.bmp");
```

As [Dan Csharpster stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488360/how-to-get-website-root-path-in-c#comment36126935_7488390) in the comments, since the `Server` object which exposes the `MapPath` method is not directly available in a class library the command should be

```
string imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/image/turnon.bmp");
```

Comment: If you are in a class that doesn't automatically have access to the HttpContext, you can call it like this:  
var imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/someImage.jpg");

Comment: HttpContext is not available as long as a session is not available, like in HTTPModule or HTTPHandler and thus it will throw exception

Answer (score 4):

**Simple 
use the ~ sign**

as the ~ represents the root of your app.

so yourimage url will be

```
<img    src='<%= Server.MapPath("~/images/1.jpg") '  />
```

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem when I was using ASP.NET MVC2. you can use this:

```
ResolveClientUrl("~/Content/Icons/loading1.gif")
or  Url.Resolve()
```

Comment: Since all of my searches for ```Url``` came back with unrelated pages, where might one find ```Url``` or ```ResolveClientUrl```?

Answer (score 2):

When you are not in a mvc / web forms context use VirtualPathUtility: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.toapprelative.aspx

```
var siteRoot = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~");
```

Comment: And what does this will return?

Answer (score 0):

This is for the root of the virtual path not the physical directory of the website on the server
In a c# MVC 5 controller this works for me.

```
string siteRoot = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~");
```