# image does not appear when changing it's image url

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, wcf

I'm a newbie in C# *and in programming in general*. I have a table is an aspx web forms page and Ι want to display some images. I get the image url by uploading a file in a specific folder then storing the full path in a database and on page load I get the image url  form the database by invoking a wcf service. The path is updated successfully in the database but the image does not appear on my page. I also tried to copy and paste the path myself and even then the image doesn't appear. I've been searching for this but still I don't know why it fails. I tried with a jpg and a gif image. Here is my code:

**account.aspx**

```
  <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"  BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="5" GridLines="vertical"   HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="572px" style="margin-left: 0px">
                    <asp:TableRow >
                        <asp:TableCell Width="192">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Στιγμιότυπο παραγγελίας:"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Width="192">
                             <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Χρονοδιάγραμμα:"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell Width="192">
                               <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Τιμολόγιο:"></asp:Label>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableRow>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                             <asp:Image ID="img_form_instance" ImageUrl="" runat="server" width="50" Height="50"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                             <asp:Image ID="img_timeschedule" ImageUrl="" runat="server" width="50"     Height="50"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell>
                             <asp:Image ID="img_invoice" ImageUrl="" runat="server" width="50" Height="50"/>
                        </asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
```

**account.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = (int)Session["UserId"];

        try
        {


            clientInfo_Ref.IclientInfoClient clInfoClient = new clientInfo_Ref.IclientInfoClient();

            List<string> rows = new List<string>(clInfoClient.getClientInfo(id));

            string column = rows.FirstOrDefault();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
            string[] columns = column.Split(';');


            name_lbl.Text = columns[0];
            sname_lbl.Text = columns[1];
            address_lbl.Text = columns[2];
            pc_lbl.Text = columns[3];
            business_lbl.Text = columns[4];
            fc_lbl.Text = columns[5];
            pfs_lbl.Text = columns[6];
            telephone_lbl.Text = columns[7];
            fax_lbl.Text = columns[8];
            mail_lbl.Text = columns[9];

        }
        catch
        {

        }

        try
        {
            accountInfo_Ref.IaccountInfoSrvcClient accInfoClient = new accountInfo_Ref.IaccountInfoSrvcClient();

            List<string> rows2 = new List<string>(accInfoClient.getAccountInfo(id));

            string column2 = rows2.FirstOrDefault();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(column2))
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
            string[] columns2 = column2.Split(';');

            //No need to display sensitive info in account page-> inclucde only safe column info
            order_id_lbl.Text = columns2[1];
            state_lbl.Text = columns2[2];
            cost_lbl.Text = columns2[3];
            img_form_instance.ImageUrl = columns2[4];
            img_timeschedule.ImageUrl = columns2[5]; 
            img_invoice.ImageUrl = columns2[6]; 
            notificatin_lbl.Text = columns2[7];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { 

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the folder you upload the images to under the web root? Can you post an example of a full url as the browser sees it?

Comment: The path in the database is this C:/Users/dv/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/NIS_Assignment/UploadedFiles/56678/65570/Invoices/webstore_invoice_quotes_samples_product_invoice.jpg

Comment: You'll need to put the image directory under the web root, or write a handler to read the file from disk and write it to the response. The second option is the way to go if you have images that only certain people should see.

Comment: you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488360/how-to-get-website-root-path-in-c? So I need to change the path I store in the database or just convert the line img_form_instance.ImageUrl = columns2[4]; ?

Comment: If you are new at programming, here is the best advice I can give you. This will greatly enhance your career. Don't ever hide problems from yourself. Problems are for you to learn from. If you hide them from yourself, then you will never learn from them and will remain just as ignorant in the future as you are today.

Comment: Don't hide exceptions with `try {bad code} catch {}` or `catch (Exception){}`.

Comment: Yes you're right I wasn't intending to leave it that way

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this did it

```
            // Replace absolute paths with relative ones
            String form_relPath = columns2[4].Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
            String schedule_relPath = columns2[5].Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
            String invoice_relPath = columns2[6].Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);

            //No need to display sensitive info in account page-> inclucde only safe column info
            order_id_lbl.Text = columns2[1];
            state_lbl.Text = columns2[2];
            cost_lbl.Text = columns2[3];
            img_form_instance.ImageUrl = form_relPath;
            img_timeschedule.ImageUrl = schedule_relPath;
            img_invoice.ImageUrl = invoice_relPath; 
            notificatin_lbl.Text = columns2[7];
```